# How to use ExecutorService with Android AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, executorservice

I need to execute a number of `AsyncTask`s and then gather all their results, consolidate and then return the final result to my user.

I am looking at a way to manage multiple `AsyncTask`s in Android. I am thinking of using a `ExecutorService` from the Java Concurrency package but I stuck because `ExecutorService` takes either Runnables or Callables ONLY. To establish my requirement I can use the

`ExecutorService.invokeAll((Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)`

The `invokeAll()` method will return a list of `List<Future><V>>` only when all submitted tasks are completed and I can get my results for each task from its corresponding `Future`.

All is well with `ExecutorService` expect for the fact that it doesn't accept `AsyncTask`.

Is there any other way to use `AsyncTask` and `ExecutorService` or if you can please recommend a different approach.

Comment: Good thing is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has method executeOnExecutor(), bad thing is it is only available since API Level 11

Comment: Any references on how to use executeOnExecutor ? Moreover this feature is available from HoneyComb(API Level 11) but my app's minSDK is 4.

Comment: If you insist, check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211684/asynctask-executeonexecutor-before-api-level-11/9509184#9509184).

Answer (score 2):

Create an `AsyncTask` and start  your threads from `doInBackground()`. When they are done, collect, consolidate, etc. the data and return it. Then you can use it in `onPostExecute` to update the UI. Starting too many thread will consume memory, so you should consider whether they really need to run in parallel.

Comment: AsyncTask itself has a pool of threads inside it. Can we use this pool to run multiple tasks instead me creating another one?

Comment: Not directly. As for `executeOnExecutor()`, the purpose of this method is to make it possible to execute multiple `AsyncTask`'s simultaneously, since the internal one can only execute one `AsyncTask` at a time (Honeycomb and later). What that means is that if you start two `AsyncTask`s more or less at the same time, the second will wait for the first to finish before it starts. If you need to do somthing more complicated, you don't have to use an `AsyncTask`, just your threading code as usual and use a Handler to notify the UI when you get the results.

Comment: It is not TRUE that "What that means is that if you start two AsyncTasks more or less at the same time, the second will wait for the first to finish before it starts"

Comment: You can use AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor for multiThread purpose.