# Android APIs and methods that are version-specific

Tags: android, android-asynctask, compatibility, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm working on a project that was originally designed for Honeycomb; we want to make it compatible with 2.3.3.  I'm doing this by converting a copy of the original project to a library project, including this library into several new projects, and subclassing some elements in the new projects to use specific APIs.

However we have lots of `AsyncTask<...>` subclasses; `AsyncTask<...>` exists in 2.3.3 but the `onCancelled()` method, which we implement, only exists since Honeycomb.  I'm concerned that if I leave these classes in the central library project, the `onCancelled()` method will not be hit because (effectively) it has been built against the 2.3.3 Android library, which doesn't have it.  However, I don't want to reproduce these classes in every sub-project without a good reason and I can't see how subclassing would make anything better: the superclass would STILL be against the 2.3.3 version of `AsyncTask<...>`.  My question is: does Java/Android allow for this, and will `onCancelled()` be hit in higher versions of Android?

Comment: you do something in onCancelled() method in Honeycomb? What will you do in 2.3.3 instead of onCancelled()?

Comment: Wait for the `AsyncTask` to complete and discard the results; in this case we call `requestCancelDecode()` on a `BitmapRegionDecoder`, which saves a bit of memory and processing and is worth doing.

Comment: PS `BitmapRegionDecoder` obviously doesn't exist pre-2.3.3 but we may want our app to run on Kindle fire devices, hence the need to extend back to 2.3.3.

Comment: Alternatively you can create your own asynctask implementation to support newly added functions down to API level 3, checkout my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211684/asynctask-executeonexecutor-before-api-level-11).

Answer (score 0):

You can relase multiple APKs. One for the honeycomb and later API level , one for the previos API levels.Otherwise you should use Compatibility package but this package doesnt support all APIs.
For multiple APKs support: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: This is in fact what we are planning to do (actually we are creating a central library project, subsidiary library projects for all Android versions with significant changes, then application projects containing the secondary libraries) but I don't want to re-implement all the `AsyncTask` subclasses in each sub-library, particularly as this means I have to make a lot of things abstract, unless I have to!  Thanks, though :)