# AsyncTasks do not get collected causing other AsyncTasks to not run

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-asynctask, threadpool

My app uses a lot of AsyncTasks. It is a web app after all. And when I keep track of the Debug tab, I notice every AsyncTask says running behind it and after 5 AsyncTasks, I can't start any AsyncTasks. I fixed it by changing the executor to `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` which allows 15 threads to be pooled. But the AsyncTasks still show as running.

The AsyncTasks all have InputStreams in them and BufferedReaders in them to read the JSON, but I never call the `close()` method on the Streamers and Readers. Could this be it, or will the AsyncTask be collected after it's finished no matter what?

If that's the deal, then why can't I run more than 5 AsyncTasks in my app?

### ***Seeing as I put a bounty on it, I will explain this more explicitly***

The `AsyncTasks` all go through their methods. All of them are built the same exact way, except with different `BasicNameValuePairs`. I am 100% sure there is no easy mistake made in the code.

Here is an example of one of the AsyncTasks:

```
private class RunningEvent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (Constants.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
            super.onPreExecute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(Void... empty) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
            values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "eventRunning"));
            values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", String
                    .valueOf(response.user.userid)));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values));

            HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

            Log.i("MenuActivity",
                    "Input streamed, parsing Gson for existing events");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);

            eventresponse = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
            return eventresponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("RunningEvent", "Error sending data to Server");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("MenuActivity", "Binding button");
        if (eventresponse != null) {
            if (eventresponse.success == 1) {
                eventresponse.user = response.user;
                bActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent i = new Intent("com.xxx.xxx.EVENT");
                        i.putExtra("response", eventresponse);
                        running = false;
                        switcher.cancel(true);
                        MenuActivity.this.finish();
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                });
            } else {
                bActivity.setText("Nieuw activity");
                bActivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent i = new Intent("com.xxx.xxx.NEWEVENT");
                        i.putExtra("response", response);
                        running = false;
                        switcher.cancel(true);
                        MenuActivity.this.finish();
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("RunningEvent", "Response is null");
        }
    }

}
```

The example above is the sometimes gets runned as the 6th `AsyncTask` and it will never enter the `doInBackground()` method. I believe this is the 5 `Thread` limit of the `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`. I "fixed" the problem by putting most `AsyncTasks` in `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, but this is just avoiding it.

What could be the reason that these `AsyncTasks` never stop running and clogging up the `Executor`?

Comment: Should the AsyncTasks be complete? What I mean is are the tasks still running normally or are they completed and are sticking around?

Comment: They stick around as Running in the ADT Debug tool.

Comment: are the tasks completing, meaning is onPostExecute() being called?

Comment: They all go through their steps and finish but thet never get collected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[android.os.AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) come with two built-in executor. if using SERIAL_EXECUTOR, there is no threadpool and all AsyncTask get execute one at a time in serial order. if using THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR (I suppose this is what you refer in the question), this allows up to maximum 128 AsyncTask get execute in parallel.

The number 5 you refer and see from debugging is the corePoolSize of underlying threadpool (AKA. THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR), which is different from maximumPoolSize. check out [AsyncTask source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and see how threadpool is implemented:

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

... ...

/**
 * An {@link Executor} that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.
 */
public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

Check out [ThreadPoolExecutor API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%3Cjava.lang.Runnable%3E,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) to see what is the default threadpool behavior created by calling this constructor. Generally speaking, **corePoolSize is the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle, unless allowCoreThreadTimeOut is set**.

Those 5 AsyncTask you see in debug are actually on core threads which are finished and become idle but never terminated, you can alter this behavior by calling [ThreadPoolExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut%28boolean%29).

---

#### More story on SERIAL_EXECUTOR

I said SERIAL_EXECUTOR does not use threadpool, this is not true. SERIAL_EXECUTOR is indeed delegate the real work to THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, but using ArrayDeque to control the submission of next tasks (next task is submitted iff the previous task is finished), check out the source:

```
private static class SerialExecutor implements Executor {
    final ArrayDeque<Runnable> mTasks = new ArrayDeque<Runnable>();
    Runnable mActive;

    public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r) {
        mTasks.offer(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    r.run();
                } finally {
                    scheduleNext();
                }
            }
        });
        if (mActive == null) {
            scheduleNext();
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void scheduleNext() {
        if ((mActive = mTasks.poll()) != null) {
            THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(mActive);
        }
    }
}
```

So whatever you use SERIAL_EXECUTOR or THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, there are always 5 core threads shown in threadpool even they are finished and become idle. However, number of core thread (configured by corePoolSize) is not the number of threads (configured by maximumPoolSize) currently running in threadpool.

Comment: This is pretty detailed and canonical, but it still doesn't answer the original question: why can't I run more than 5 Asynctasks in my app? They clearly don't finish, but all code is run.

Comment: Did you click the dynamic binding button bActivity (I assume this is a button object) during multiple AsyncTask execution?

Comment: Nope they trigger in the onCreate method. You don"t understand. All the AsyncTasks are the same, but they don't run after 5 of them have been called.

Comment: You misunderstand my question, I am not asking how your AsyncTask is triggered. The potential problem in your code is in AysncTask.onPostExecute() implementation, depend on the conditional logic, you create button that finish current activity `MenuActivity.this.finish();` if you click it, current activity is destroy, as a consequence, all its running and pending AsyncTask becomes non-referenceable and create black hole in memory. Other than that, I don't see any fault point that may result this unexpected behavior in your code.

Comment: Now I get it. I don have a problem with that. The code above **sometimes** gets run as the 6th AsyncTask. It is usually the 2nd AsyncTask. If I click around and go back to the menu, it should check if I started an "Event", and if so, it should go to a different activity. But the code itself does work.

Comment: I moved my `OnClickListeners` out of the `onPostExecute()` method, and my problem is gone! Seeing as you told me about your 'black hole in the memory' it got me thinking if the AsyncTasks are kept alive because there are `OnClickListeners` assigned in them. Thanks!