# Async task thread source

Tags: android

I'm wondering about the relation between async task and threads?  Each one create a new one, Is it cached, pooled.

Comment: Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705285/asynctasks-do-not-get-collected-causing-other-asynctasks-to-not-run/12232358#12232358) may help you understand how AsyncTask is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Asynctask uses a serial executor, so a single thread is used to execute all the asynctasks in a single process. But you can change it.

Check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

> Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to being executed on a single
>   thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel
>   execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR;

You can also check the source of Asynctask [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java)

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation itself, AsyncTasks allow "painless multithreading", so AsyncTasks obviously use threads in the background.

I recently profiled my app using DDMS plugin in Eclipse, an app which launches AsyncTasks at regular (and quite close) intervals. Using DDMS, you can see the number of threads currently running, and their names.

From what i saw there, the AsyncTasks use a thread pool to manage AsyncTasks. In my case, there were 5 threads named "AsyncTask #1" to "AsyncTask #5", activated one after the other in a cycle.

Hope this answers part of your question!

Comment: AsyncTask uses a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with at least 5 threads. The default serial executor (>= Honeycomb) will submit task by task (waiting for the task to complete, then submit the next task) to the pool executor which chooses a thread to run the task on. Could be a cycle but probably does not have to be.