# AsyncTask: Task 6 to 15 not starting (but running)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was testing AsyncTask details and stumbled on the issue that when I start muliple tasks, the tasks 6 to 15 (10 tasks always) are in status RUNNING, but do not get into doInBackground (where the start time is set). The next 100 tasks are started immediately.

[image: Task Example]
<sub>(source: [beadsoft.de](http://beadsoft.de/android/tasknotrunning.png))</sub>

The tasks are started pretty simple:

```
        int tasksToStart = TASKS_TO_ADD_ON_CLICK;
        while (tasksToStart > 0) {
            tasksToStart--;
            mTask = new MyTask(TASK_RUNNING_TIME);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                mTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            else
                mTask.execute();
            tvTaskInfo.setText("Task " + mTask.id + " requested.");
        }
```

This leads to the situation that all later started tasks have to be finished (meaning total running tasks is less than 5) before tasks 5 actually starts doing something.

a) Is there a way to force start the tasks?

b) Why is the status RUNNING if it does not do anything. Should it not be PENDING?

I do not have an android 4.x real device and cannot test there. In the emulator same limitations apply.

Anyone interested can download this sample project [here](http://beadsoft.de/android/AsyncTaskTest.zip).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Check the topic under order of execution

Comment: What is the use of that? It is not the order I have a problem with or parallel execution in general. I have a problem with tasks 5 to 16 not starting.

Comment: For parrallel execution use a executor http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html. Don't use asynctask for parallel execution

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html. also check this link. check the thread pool

Comment: Thanks for those links. It was more academic. It turns out the problem with not starting task is only if the AsyncTask uses Thread.sleep. My tasks did not do much.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run multiple `AsyncTasks` more than 5 (which is the default `Executor` limit), you need to start it with a different `Executor`, like this:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

The [THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) Allows you to execute up to 15 parallel AsyncTasks, whereas [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) only allows up to 5, in serial order.

Comment: No, I do that. Same issue, I can start 100 tasks parallel, but tasks 5 to 16 will not start.

Comment: You know, Gunnar, you should see [my question regarding this issue you're having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705285/asynctasks-do-not-get-collected-causing-other-asynctasks-to-not-run). I never had to start more than 15 AsyncTasks though so the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR had fixed it for me, but my ATs also never actually 'finished' causing the other Asynctasks not to run.