# ASyncTask on Executor and PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to make some ASyncTask  to run simultaneously with a priority.

I've creating a ThreadPoolExecutor with an PriorityBlockingQueue and the propper comparator works nice for standard Runnables.
But when calling

```
    new Task().executeOnExecutor(threadPool, (Void[]) null);
```

The Comparator of the PriorityBlockingQueue receives a Runnable (private) internal  of the ASyncTask (called mFuture in the source code), so in the comparator I can't identify the runnables or read a "priority" value.

How can I solve that? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borrow source code from [android.os.AsyncTask](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and make your own com.company.AsyncTask implementation, where you can control everything you want in your own code.

android.os.AsyncTask come with two ready baked executor, THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR and SERIAL_EXECUTOR:

```
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);

/**
 * An {@link Executor} that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.
 */
public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);

/**
 * An {@link Executor} that executes tasks one at a time in serial
 * order. This serialization is global to a particular process.
 */
public static final Executor SERIAL_EXECUTOR = new SerialExecutor();
```

in your com.company.AsyncTask, create another PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR and wrap all your implementation within this class (where you have visiablity to all internal fields), and use your AysncTask like so:

```
com.company.AsyncTask asyncTask = new com.company.AsyncTask();
asyncTask.setPriority(1);
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(com.company.AsyncTask.PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[]) null);
```

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211684/asynctask-executeonexecutor-before-api-level-11) and see how I create my own AsyncTask to make executeOnExecutor() works before API Level 11.

Comment: Hello. I would love to follow this suggestion (because I already have a working `CustomAsyncTask`), but I'm lost at the `PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` ThreadPoolExecutor declaration. Could you give some insights? Thanks.

Comment: @demtex, PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR does not exist in official AsyncTask API, you need write it by yourself in your own CustomAsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks, I'm explaining it better here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461534/asynctask-on-executor-and-priorityblockingqueue-implementation-issue