# How to change priority of a single ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was wondering how I could force a new `ASyncTask` in Android to be the next task executed. Imagine I have multiple `ASyncTask`'s to load content from the internet, e.g. in my case I pre-load all objects of `DataModelA`, `DataModelB` and `DataModelC`. All the data is loaded to a central application model. I guess my current queue would look like this (but I do not manage it as a queue, yet):

```
1. DataModelA-Object1
2. DataModelA-Object2
3. DataModelA-Object3
4. DataModelB-Object1
5. DataModelB-Object2
6. DataModelB-Object3
7. DataModelB-Object4
8. DataModelC-Object1
9. DataModelC-Object2
10. ...
```

I start my tasks like this:

```
DataModelALoaderTask task = new DataModelALoaderTask();
task.execute("http://my-rest-api.com/datamodel/a"); 

// and the same for the other tasks
...
```

The task class looks like this:

```
private class DataModelALoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<DataModelA>> {  
    @Override
    protected List<DataModelA> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String data = params[0];
        return DataModelAContentProvider.loadContentFromUrl(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<DataModelA> models) {
        // finally add the loaded content to the central application data model
        ...
    }
}
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

Now within my GUI, I like to click on a button and force to load a single part of a model first, because I need to display it right now. Usually this is a task which is already in the queue, but in my case I could also just start a new task, e.g. to load `DataModelC-Object2` first before all others are loaded. The queue could load a large number of objects, so that it makes sense to re-schedule a single task or start a new task which does the job immediately.

Any idea how I can handle that? If you would need to see more code snippets, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Michael

**UPDATE:** somehow my question seems to be related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039596/asynctask-on-executor-and-priorityblockingqueue). Is that the only way? Or could I simply start a parallel running task using the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`? How would I use that?