# LoopJ and Google Maps in the same time

Tags: android, google-maps, loopj

I'm experiencing delay with single httppost while GMaps is downloading maps over mobile network. Once single httppost took 7min to finish. Is there a way to prioritize request or temporarily pause GMaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `getMap()` and `setUpMap()` methods in an `AsyncTask`. And I found some related issue on how to prioritize AsyncTask. Hope this gives you an idea. [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039596/asynctask-on-executor-and-priorityblockingqueue)