# Backward compatibility and SDK updates in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Since I need the `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()` function targeting the `SDK level 7` I've took the last `ASyncTask` code and created a `mAsyncTask` class.

I'd like to use `mAsyncTask` if the `API level is < 11` and the Android's default `AsyncTask` (in order to seize the future SDK updates.

Since the definition of an `AsyncTask` extension can take a lot of lines. It is ugly and hard maintainable to copy/paste and make one extend of each class (`mAsyncTask` and `AsyncTask`) and then in run-time execute one or the other.

Is there a trick I could use for avoiding this problem?

Thanks

Comment: check: [AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor() before API Level 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211684/asynctask-executeonexecutor-before-api-level-11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't subclass the "real" AsyncTask using relfexion, the only way is to create separate APKs.